# need more information on double data type in vbs

Tags: vba, vbscript, type-conversion, hp-uft

I could see double is storing 15 digits in VBS, But in msdn documentation it's given as "-1.79769313486231E308" please clarify

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa263420(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Double doesn't necessarily mean *"15 digits"*, it's an 8-byte floating point number. How that's displayed depends on the value and the language.

Answer (score 3):

In VBS, the double data type is [described](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9e7a57cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) as

> **Double:** Contains a double-precision, floating-point number in the range -1.79769313486232E308 to -4.94065645841247E-324 for negative
>   values; 4.94065645841247E-324 to 1.79769313486232E308 for positive
>   values.

the same [definition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264155.aspx) found for VBA, where it is indicated that it is a `IEEE 64 bit (8-byte) floating-point numbers`

This correspond to a [IEEE 754 double-precision binary floating-point format: binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) with

```
Sign bit: 1 bit
Exponent: 11 bits
Significand precision: 53 bits (52 explicitly stored)
```

Where

> The 11 bit width of the exponent allows the representation of numbers
>   between 10<sup>−308</sup> and 10<sup>308</sup>, with full 15–17 decimal digits precision. By
>   compromising precision, the subnormal representation allows even
>   smaller values up to about 5 × 10<sup>−324</sup>.